# How could BUY price be higher than SELL price

Tags: stock-markets

Please have a look at the image:

[image]

How this could be possible. Why transactions are not made?

Comment: What does the image show? What does each line represent? Is the price varying over time?

Comment: Time and sales depicts a bid, ask, last trade, volume, as well as buy size and sell size.  A running list of single prices and two volume numbers  is meaningless data.

Comment: I think this is supposed to be a snapshot of an order book (note that price is shown in uniform 5 cent increments). If the left column shows buy orders by price and the right column shows sell orders by price at the same instant, OP seems to be asking how the buy order at $53.70 can exist without being immediately matched with the sell order at $52.85. In other words, is this a crossed market?

Answer (score 0):

There could be any number of reasons why:

- the market is closed (and the orders pending),
- the chart could be a graph of the aftermarket, consolidated across exchanges - order protection rules do not during the aftermarket session,
- the orders could have constraints such as being 'all-or-nothing' which prevents them from being executed in the normal manner, or
- the chart is delayed or there are artifacts in the data.

Obviously the reason why that should not be the case, is someone buy at 53,800 at 52.85 and immediately sell that 53,800 at 53.80, making a 0.95 profit per share for a total of 51,110 less transaction costs.  Usually there are people (or algorithms) already waiting for such opportunities.